# RMarkdown Prevent code outputs from breaking across pages

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

In RMarkdown using the PDF output option, sometimes the outputs of code blocks get split between pages (as shown in sample below. This sometimes yields outputs where just a small section of the output is on one page and the larger section is on another page.

[image: Sample output showing block output split between pages]

Microsoft Word has the option to enable the *Widow/Orphan control* option which prevents such separation.

> Is there any similar option I can enable in RMarkdown to merge consecutive blocks across pages if one section is less than a certain number of lines?

My current approach involves cross-referencing the output and putting a `\newline` before code blocks that get split between two pages. Obviously, this is needlessly complicated and quite prone to errors.

Answer (score 6):

By default, code chunk output is put within the latex `verbatim` environment. But you can use the `Verbatim` environment with `samepage`  option from the latex package [`fancyvrb` (See the manual, p.17)](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/doc/fancyvrb-doc.pdf) to keep together the whole output of a code-chunk.

Therefore, You can modify the knitr [`output` hooks](https://yihui.org/knitr/hooks/#output-hooks) to use `Verbatim[[samepage=true]` instead of `verbatim`, which would be enabled based on the chunk-option `nobreak`.

So if you want the no-page-break behavior for a specific chunk, set the chunk option `nobreak` as `TRUE` for a specific chunk, or if you want the no-page-break behavior for all chunk output, use `nobreak=TRUE` in `knitr::opts_chunk$set`.

````
---
title: "No Page Break for Outputs"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{lipsum}
  - \usepackage{fancyvrb}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, nobreak=TRUE)
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)

default_output_hook <- knit_hooks$get('output')

knit_hooks$set(
  output = function(x, options) {
    if(is.null(options$nobreak)) {
      default_output_hook(x, options)
    } else {
      paste0("\\begin{Verbatim}[samepage=true]\n", x, "\n\\end{Verbatim}"
        )
    }
  }
)
```

\lipsum[1-5]

## R code

```{r}
t.test(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars)
```
````

---

[image: code output with no-page-break]

---

*Note: I have the latex package `lipsum` just to generate random text, it is not relevant to the problem/solution here.*

Comment: Great solution! Would this solution also work if output is produced using, e.g. a for loop?

Comment: I can not say for sure. It should work, since it is simply wrapping the output with `Verbatim[samepage=true]` instead of `verbaitm`. Can you give me some code to test? (I am curious too)

Comment: If there are multiple lines of code inside a block (which happens rather often), this method fails with the error *! FancyVerb Error: Extraneous input `\begin{Verbatim}[samepage=true]\end{}…*. The only way around this is to set the ```results='hold'``` option on the chunk.

Comment: @AlexEssilfie, It is working in my case. I am not getting any error with multiple line of codes in a same code chunk.

Comment: @AlexEssilfie, can you elaborate on the issues you were facing with this solution?

Answer (score 3):

You could warp the verbatim environment into a `minipage`, which can't be broken across pages:

````
---
title: "No Page Break for Outputs"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{lipsum}
  - \AddToHook{env/verbatim/begin}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
  - \AddToHook{env/verbatim/end}{\end{minipage}}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\lipsum[1-5]

## R code

```{r}
t.test(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars)
```
````

This can also be used to only make one code chunk unbreakable while keeping the default behaviour for other ones:

````
---
title: "No Page Break for Outputs"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{lipsum}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\lipsum[1-5]

## R code

\AddToHookNext{env/verbatim/begin}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
\AddToHookNext{env/verbatim/end}{\end{minipage}}
```{r}
t.test(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars)
```
````

Comment: Isn't `nobreak=TRUE` unnecessary in your answer? :)

Comment: @shafee Yes :) Thank you for providing a minimal working example :)

Answer (score 1):

While the [answer by samcarter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75557143/117870) does the job very well, I find that unless you want all output chunks to not break across pages, it is preferable to have an output hook that can be turned on or off for each block. That way, you can achieve the desired result without having to repeat the `\AddHookToNext` option for each block.

The following is a sample code with the output hook that achieves the result described in the question.

````
---
title: "No Page Break for Outputs"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{lipsum}

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(nobreaks=F)  # set to TRUE or FALSE depending on desired defaults
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
default_output_hook <- knitr::knit_hooks$get('output')
  
knitr::knit_hooks$set(
  output = function(x, options) {
    result = default_output_hook(x, options)
    
    if (isTRUE(options$nobreaks)){
      result = paste0("\\AddToHookNext{env/verbatim/begin}{\\begin{minipage}{\\linewidth}}\n",
                      "\\AddToHookNext{env/verbatim/end}{\\end{minipage}}\n", 
                      result)
    }
    
    result
  }
)
```


# Text

\lipsum[1-5]


# R code

```{r echo=F, nobreaks=T}
t.test(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars)
t.test(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars)
```
````

Setting the `nobreaks` chunk option to `T` or `F` toggles between disallowing and allowing page breaks in output blocks respectively.
Additionally, setting the `results` to `'hold'` makes all consecutive outputs stay together on the same page as far as practicable.